# How to set a responsive chart.js chart to not fill screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I want to set the height of my chart to be a percentage of it's containing div. How do I do this?

It's such a simple question, but if I set the chart `responsive: false`, then I can stretch it but it is out of proportion, as the underlying height and width are already set.

If I set it as `responsive: true` then the chart will spill out of the containing div and fill the screen.

If I set the containing div's CSS to `contain: content`, then I can just see the top of the graph.

What should I do?

e.g.

```
<div style="display: block; width: 80%; height: 30%; margin-left:10%;">
    <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [colors]="colors" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="'false'"
        [chartType]="'bar'" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just look documentation a little bit but i think  [this link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-scale-types) can fix your problem . At the Scale Properties has a height attribute. im using devexpress chart for my project if u can buy product it's too much easier then other graphic libraries.